# Need help formatting PHP conditional statement for Wordpress website

Tags: php, conditional-statements

This is the original, unedited, code which checks to see whether the excerpt or full content has been selected in the the theme's options.

```
<?php if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] ) && $woo_options['woo_post_content'] == 'content' ) { the_content( __( 'Continue Reading &rarr;', 'woothemes' ) ); } else { the_excerpt(); } ?>
```

I want to add `<?php if (is_home() ) { <?php the_content(); ?>` to the start of this statement so that the homepage always displays the full post.

I have tried the following but it's not working:

```
<?php if (is_home()) { ?> <?php the_content(); ?> elseif ( isset( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] ) && $woo_options['woo_post_content'] == 'content' ) { the_content( __( 'Continue Reading &rarr;', 'woothemes' ) ); } else { the_excerpt(); }} ?>
```

Comment: how is it now working?

Comment: It's working now. Seems I had an extra php quote where I didn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you just put some extra php quotes:

```
<?php 
if (is_home()) { the_content(); 
} elseif ( isset( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] )  && $woo_options['woo_post_content'] == 'content' ) { 
  the_content( __( 'Continue Reading &rarr;', 'woothemes' ) );
} else { 
    the_excerpt(); 
} 
?>
```